# Listen computer's sound on Android

Tags: android, audio

My computer's jack plug is broken and it has no bluetooth. But I would like to hear its sound with my headset, so I was wondering if there's a way to listen it through my Android phone, over WiFi or USB, it doesn't matter.

Do you know any app/method that could do that ? (I would like to have it for tomorrow so I have no time to code PC server+phone app ^^, but if you have a whole code, I can compile it)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with VLC.

Install VLC for windows on your PC, and choose File... Stream... Capture device and designate which sound card to capture.  For Video device, choose 'None'.  For Destination Setup, choose HTTP and assign some port and path, such as 8080, /pcaudio.

Install VLC for Android on your phone.  Open a stream to play, and type the path to your windows source stream.  Something like http://192.168.x.x:8080/pcaudio
Of course, use the IP address or hostname of your windows machine.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this afternoon

Comment: In my case, only audio *inputs* show up in the list of devices. Audio outputs do not.

Answer (score 2):

or you can use app its's called soundwire, it's availble for server and client side https://oopsreview.com/soundwire-listen-to-sound-from-computer-on-android/